# PyQT5 crashes when trying to replace the widget inside a QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a main window in which I have a QGridLayout section containing multiple images. The grid resizes as the main window resizes. When the main window resizes, it calls resize_event in the file where the contents of the main window are implemented.

Since there are a lot of product images, resizing the main window by dragging the window's corner causes multiple resizeEvent calls within my main window, which causes the gallery to be resized multiple times, greatly slowing down the program.

To solve this, I using threads to only call the function that restructures the grid after a delay. Unfortunately, the program launches then crashes. What is causing my problem?

I am including all code for completeness's sake.

**Main window**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

import GUIProductGalleryModule
import GUIProductEditorModule

import GUIMainMenu

from screeninfo import get_monitors         # used to get the user's resolution for max screen size


class GUIMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # get screen size
        monitors = get_monitors()

        # set the Window's minimum size according to the width of images in the product gallery plus a constant
        white_space = 50
        self.setMinimumSize(GUIProductGalleryModule.image_width + white_space, GUIProductGalleryModule.image_height + white_space)
        
        self.screen_width = monitors[0].width
        self.screen_height = monitors[0].height

        self.max_screen_width = self.screen_width - 100
        self.max_screen_height = self.screen_height - 100

        # set up the main window
        self.setGeometry(0, 30, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ploutos!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\\Users\\Ze\\Documents\\Dropshipping\\Design\\Program\\Icon.png'))

        # set the home page to the Product Gallery
        self.home_module = GUIProductGalleryModule
        self.active_module = self.home_module

        # initialize the product gallery
        self.product_gallery = GUIProductGalleryModule
        self.product_editor = GUIProductEditorModule

        self.main_menu = GUIMainMenu.set_main_menu(self)

    def activate_product_gallery(self):
        self.active_module = GUIProductGalleryModule

        self.active_module.home(self)

    def activate_product_editor(self, product_id):
        self.active_module = GUIProductEditorModule

        self.active_module.home(self, product_id)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        if self.active_module is not None:
            self.active_module.resize_event(self)

    def launch(self):
        self.home_module.home(self)

        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit',
                                            "Are you sure you would like to quit?",
                                            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

**Product gallery:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QScrollArea, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QThread
import GUIClickableLabel

import GUIThreadWorker

import math

image_width = 300
image_height = 300

standard_font = QFont("Times", 24, QFont.Bold)

# the time to wait after a resizing to draw the gallery to avoid slowness
redraw_delay = 0.5


def home(main_window: QMainWindow):
    set_up_window(main_window)

    # pass the parameters directly to the class because the slot function takes no parameters
    parameters = [redraw_delay, reset_gallery, main_window]

    global thread_worker
    for p in parameters:
        thread_worker.execute_function_with_timer_parameters.append(p)

    # for clarity       = this worker function executes any given function within a given amount of time. One can .add_time(float)
    function_to_execute = thread_worker.execute_function_with_timer

    global thread
    # connect thread's started signal to worker's operational slot method
    thread.started.connect(function_to_execute)


def resize_event(main_window):
    # get rid of compiler warning
    type(main_window)

    global thread

    if not thread.isRunning():
        thread.start()


def reset_gallery(main_window):
    # reposition images
    new_layout = set_up_gallery(main_window)

    # vertical container that contains the top area with the title and filters and the bottom area with the scroll area within which the product gallery is located
    central_widget = main_window.centralWidget()

    vertical_layout = central_widget.layout()

    scroll_area_index = 1
    scroll_area = vertical_layout.itemAt(scroll_area_index).widget()

    new_product_gallery = scroll_area.takeWidget()

    QWidget().setLayout(new_product_gallery.layout())

    new_product_gallery.setLayout(new_layout)


    scroll_area.setWidget(new_product_gallery)


def resetting_finished():
    thread.quit()


def set_up_gallery(main_window):
    product_gallery_layout = QGridLayout()

    max_images = 60

    images = []

    columns_that_fit = math.floor(main_window.size().width() / image_width)

    desired_number_columns = columns_that_fit if columns_that_fit > 1 else 1

    for row in range(math.ceil(max_images / desired_number_columns)):
        for column in range(desired_number_columns):
            index = desired_number_columns * row + column
            name = index if index < 39 else 1

            image = QWidget()

            product_id = 10000000977217

            image.im = QPixmap("C:\\Users\\Ze\\Documents\\Dropshipping\\Varied\\Temp\\Photos\\Pills\\Untitled-" + str(name) + ".jpg")
            image.label = GUIClickableLabel.GUIClickableLabel(main_window.activate_product_editor, product_id)
            image.label.setPixmap(image.im.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            image.label.setFixedSize(QSize(image_height, image_height))

            product_gallery_layout.addWidget(image.label, row, column, Qt.AlignCenter)

            images.append(image)

    for column in range(product_gallery_layout.columnCount()):
        product_gallery_layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(column, image_width)

    return product_gallery_layout


def set_up_window(main_window: QMainWindow):
    # PRODUCT GALLERY
    # stores all products
    product_gallery = QWidget()
    product_gallery_layout = set_up_gallery(main_window)

    vertical_container = QWidget()
    vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    top_container = QHBoxLayout()
    product_gallery_title = QLabel("Product Gallery")
    product_gallery_title.setFont(standard_font)
    product_gallery_title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    top_container.addWidget(product_gallery_title)

    vertical_layout.addLayout(top_container)

    # set up the scroll area where the product gallery will be so that it stretches automatically
    scroll_area = QScrollArea()
    scroll_area.setWidget(product_gallery)
    scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll_area.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    vertical_layout.addWidget(scroll_area)

    vertical_container.setLayout(vertical_layout)

    product_gallery.setLayout(product_gallery_layout)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(vertical_container)


thread_worker = GUIThreadWorker.GUIThreadWorker()
thread_worker.task_finished_signal.connect(resetting_finished)
thread = QThread()
thread_worker.moveToThread(thread)
```

**Threading**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal

import time


# this class runs the GUI thread
class GUIThreadWorker(QObject):
    timers = []

    time_last_checked = 0

    # parameter order is (time_until_execution, function_to_execute, function_parameters)
    execute_function_with_timer_parameters = []

    time_until_execution_index = 0
    function_to_execute_index = 1
    function_parameters_index = 2

    time_remaining = 0
    task_finished_signal = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def execute_function_with_timer(self):

        time_last_checked = time.time()

        while True:
            # update time until execution
            current_time = time.time()

            # time since last checked
            time_elapsed = current_time - time_last_checked

            # time remaining until execution
            self.time_remaining = self.time_remaining - time_elapsed

            # if time to execute
            if self.time_remaining <= 0:
                # the function to be executed when the time is up
                function_to_execute = self.execute_function_with_timer_parameters[self.function_to_execute_index]

                # the parameters to pass to this function
                parameters = self.execute_function_with_timer_parameters[self.function_parameters_index]

                function_to_execute(parameters)

                self.task_finished_signal.emit()

                break

            # reset last checked time
            time_last_checked = current_time
```

Comment: The cause is that UI elements are not thread safe, and should *never* be accessed by external threads. The situation of multiple resizing widgets is complex, and its implementation depends on the situation. I cannot test your code right now, but an important aspect is to be able to compute the resizing in the *smarter* way. Are those elements all of the same size?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! This is what it looks like: https://pasteboard.co/eFa9lvjCktwZ.png. What do you recommend? The images vary in resolution but are usually above 600x600 and there are not thumbnails to make it easier (millions of images).

Comment: With that amount of images, using a unique QWidget for each image is not the right choice: while hundreds or even thousands of widgets is not a big problem for memory, it becomes an issue for the CPU, as the layout *always* has to query *all* its contents whenever it's being resized, and *also* for memory since you're loading the pixmaps for each label: even if the source images are compressed, the memory usage of the loaded image is not, and just 1000 600x600 images can occupy more than 1gb (assuming they don't have an alpha channel). The only proper way to do a gallery with an undefined ->

Comment: -> amount of images that has good performance for both memory and CPU is to use a QAbstractTableModel subclass and show it in a QListView using `setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)`. This ensures that the layout is always based on a standard grid (which you can decide) and that the data is only loaded upon request. You can then implement some optimization such as limited caching and preloading, so that scrolling doesn't make the view unresponsive, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: That sounds perfect, thanks so much!